# Modify physical_name from my sys.master_files in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I freshly installed SQL Server on my new Windows 11 machine, but I can't start the `MSSQLSERVER` service. I get an error that some files can't be found (example: `d:\dbs\sh\s19s\0924_133725\cmd\2\obj\x64retail\sql\mkmastr\databases\mkmastr.proj\model.mdf`). They can't be found because that path doesn't exist, I don't have a `d:\` drive. I want to know how is it possible to modify the physical_name of my files ?

```
SELECT name, physical_name 
FROM sys.master_files;
```

Returns:

```
name                     physical_name                                                                                               
----------------------   -----------------------------------------------------
master                   C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\master.mdf                             
mastlog                  C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\mastlog.ldf                            
tempdev                  d:\dbs\sh\s19s\0924_133725\cmd\2\obj\x64retail\sql\mkmastr\databases\mkmastr.proj\tempdb.mdf                
templog                  d:\dbs\sh\s19s\0924_133725\cmd\2\obj\x64retail\sql\mkmastr\databases\mkmastr.proj\templog.ldf               
modeldev                 d:\dbs\sh\s19s\0924_133725\cmd\2\obj\x64retail\sql\mkmastr\databases\mkmastr.proj\model.mdf                 
modellog                 d:\dbs\sh\s19s\0924_133725\cmd\2\obj\x64retail\sql\mkmastr\databases\mkmastr.proj\modellog.ldf              
MSDBData                 d:\dbs\sh\s19s\0924_133725\cmd\2\obj\x64retail\sql\mkmastr\databases\mkmastr.proj\MSDBData.mdf              
MSDBLog                  d:\dbs\sh\s19s\0924_133725\cmd\2\obj\x64retail\sql\mkmastr\databases\mkmastr.proj\MSDBLog.ldf               

(8 rows affected)
```

and

```
SELECT name, filename FROM sysfiles
```

returns:

```
name                      physical_name                                                                                               
----------------------    -------------------------------------------------------------
master                    C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\master.mdf                             
mastlog                   C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\mastlog.ldf
```

```
ALTER TABLE sys.master_files
```

doesn't do anything.

Comment: Have you tried the method here? serverfault.com/a/447894/39535 (to use the `f` switch to start it with [minimal configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/database-engine-service-startup-options?view=sql-server-ver16#other-startup-options) in conjunction with trace flag 3608 then `ALTER DATABASE ... MODIFY FILE`)? Though TBH a reinstall is probably the best option as looks like something has gone wrong and who knows if this is the only problem?

Comment: I agree with @MartinSmith a reinstall is your best option. If the problem continues, check the install logs.

Comment: OK, that was it, I could update my files using the method @MartinSmith you gave, thank you